# How to display a rails link_to in a raw (or simple_format) text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an image model with an attribute :description which is a text, formatted as html text (e.g. with a few 
 in the text), which I display in a view as follows:

```
simple_format(@image.description)
```

raw(@image.description) will do mainly the same I think. How can I add a link_to helper with a link into that text? I'm searching for something like the following text (which will be @image.description):

Text text text text.
Text text #{link_to "Text", @image.link)

@image.link will be the link. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ERB:

```
<%= raw ERB.new(@image.description).result(binding) %>
```

Wrap it in a helper method:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def simple_format(content)
    ERB.new(content).result(binding).html_safe
  end
end
```

And use it like:

```
<%= simple_format(@image.description) %>
```

Some example content you could use for your image description could be:

```
Check out <%= link_to "the first image", image_path(1) %>!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this bit of code

```
link_to raw(@image.description), @image.link
```

If you need select only one random word:

```
words = @image.description.split

link_to raw(words.sample), @image.link
```

**UPDATE:**

For example when you create description you can add special symbols to word which you can use as link for example it can be brackets:

```
@image.description = This my description with link (Hello) you can follow it!

@image.description.gsub(/\(([^\)]+)\)/, link_to('\1', @image.link))
```

It will produce:

```
"This my description with link <a href=\"/\">Hello</a> you can follow it!"
```

Comment: Thanks. But this means the link will be displayed as the last word in the text. How can I get a link also in the middle of the text?

Comment: Ok, but isn't there a way to do this inside the text of @image.description? This way I'm flexible to create links for all different images whereever I need without changing the view...